# spring data neo4j graph repository not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I´m newbie in spring data neo4j and I have some errors/questions with the GraphRepository.

I first had this:

```
import guru.springframework.domain.Product;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<Product> {

   Product findById(Long id);

    Product deleteById(Long id);
}
```

But reading some documentation, the repository already provides such methods. I don´t need to write them.

This is my Product domain

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

import java.math.BigDecimal;


@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is my test class

```
   @Test
    public void testPersistence() {

        productRepository.deleteAll();
        //given
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setDescription(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION);
        product.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL);
        product.setPrice(BIG_DECIMAL_100);

        //when
        productRepository.save(product);

        //then
        Assert.assertNotNull(product.getId());

        //Product newProduct = productRepository.findById(product.getId()).orElse(null);


        Product newProduct = productRepository.findById(182L);
```

The findById is not detected

[image: error]

Is that normal?

This is my 
 [pom.xml](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-neo4j-example/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: you have to write the method in your ProductRepository. Spring data will understand the query it needs to execute from your method name. You dont need to write the query, but you need to write a method declaration like you have written `findById(...)`. it should be recognised from your test class

Comment: yes, I tried that way before, but when I performed the test, I got a NullException , and I do have that node stored (182L). In the tutorial, they have this Product newProduct = productRepository.findById(product.getId()).orElse(null); But in my case the orElse() is not recognized. Does that help to avoid the exception? here you can see the file (line 43) https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-neo4j-example/blob/master/src/test/java/guru/springframework/repositories/ProductRepositoryTest.java

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring Data Neo4j 5.x you should extend `Neo4jRepository` not `GraphRepository`.

The `GraphRepository` used to be present in older versions. You depend on `spring-boot 2.0.0.M7`, which transitively depends on SDN 5.

If `GraphRepository` is recognised by your IDE than you have another problem in your project settings.